# First Angular app not outputting from controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm still very new at this and this is my first attempt to making an app without following any guide. For some reason my output in the webpage is {{$scope.products}} instead of the actual values. Can anyone tell my why it won't load the angular code from the controller?

index.html

```
 <<!doctype html ng-app="MyFirstApp"> 
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainController as ctrl">
{{ctrl.name}}
{{"Hello World"}}

</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
  var app = angular.module('MyFirstApp', [])
.controller('MainController', function(){

this.name = "Joe";

});
```

Comment: don't put $scope in the HTML

Comment: try ng-repeat for an array

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/C4XuA3kGEoDywhiZYfGL?p=info

Comment: and you should try a guide, it would help

Comment: I fixed the $scope in HTML, but it's not recognizing any angular code as if I didn't put the script src in?

Comment: well, it would be products[0].title to get the first title as products is an array

Comment: I have updated your code and added a working example. Click `Run code snippet` in my answer.

Comment: I understand that your code works, but why wouldn't {{"Hello World"}} output as Hello World instead of {{"Hello World"}} ?

Comment: I just figured it out. It's because I had ng-app="MyFirstApp in <!doctype html> I got it working by moving it to opening body tag

Comment: Because any JavaScript-like expression is interpolated within the curly-braces. This is a common template feature used by many tools, not just AngularJS.

Answer (score 1):

Your snippet contains some errors:

- `<!doctype html ng-app="MyFirstApp">` : ngApp directive is too high. Please put it in the `<body>` tag at least.
- `ng-controller="MainController as ctrl"`: if it is your very first AJS example, be aware that controllerAs is a best practice, but a bit advanced. This choice will condition slightly the controller code.
- `{{products.title}}`: products is an array!
- `... .controller('MainController',[$scope function($scope){`: the second argument of `controller` method is an array, so between `$scope` and `function` a comma is needed. In your case the array must be: `['$scope',function($scope){...}]`. For more info pls see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di
- `$scope.products = [...];` : in order to avoid controllerAs antipattern you must use `this.products`.

Please update your code.

Comment: This is a very good answer. But you probably don't need to inject `$scope` using the `controllerAs` syntax. Should be `.controller('MainController', function() {`

Comment: You're right! I forgot it ;) . It is only needed if you want to use methods like `$watch`...  that is quite like daily bread...

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('MyFirstApp', [])
.controller('MainController', function(){
  
  this.name = "Joe"

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyFirstApp" ng-controller="MainController as ctrl">
  {{ctrl.name}}
</div>
```

AngularJS documentation can be quite confusing.

Assigning values to the `$scope` is considered a bad practice. This is one of the things that the `controllerAs` syntax solves. So instead of adding the products to `$scope.products` -- add them to `this.name`.

Then in your view you will access them with `{{ctrl.name}}`

I hope this helps.

Comment: it is not considered bad practice. it is only not the best practice for large applications in order to avoid "scope-soup".

Comment: Unless you are working with isolated scopes, I would disagree.

Comment: If I change all my code and replace it with your code, then It still won't recognize the angular code. My output wouldn't be My Title. It would be {{ctrl.products[0].title}}. I updated my code above to display an even simpler example where it will output {{ctrl.products.name}} instead of Joe. I still don't know why this is happening. It's like it's not recognizing the angular script src. If I write {{"Hello World"}} in my index.html file then the output won't be Hello World, but {{"Hello World"}}

Comment: @user6680 I see you have updated your code and have gotten rid of the array. Ill update my code example to reflect that.-- as @morels points out, you can't put the `ng-app` in the !doctype tag.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the dependancy to your controller between '' and
 you are missing some thing after $scope

.controller('MainController',['$scope',function($scope){

}]);

and there are no iterate for the array in your controller to be bind in html